# Rebalancing AVL Tree after insertion

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I am writing code for an AVL tree data structure to be used in a word game I am creating. The AVL tree is used to store words from a dictionary text file in alphabetical order for quick and easy access. I have confirmed that I can implement my dictionary as a binary search tree, however I am having difficulty implementing it as an AVL tree, more specifically when I rebalance after rotations.

I am testing my code out by simply using pre,in, and postorder traversal to see if my whole tree is implemented correctly. The issue I have is that I am only able to recover 6/22 words. I have isolated one of the causes to be that I did not update my root after a rotation was performed around it, but for some reason it only updates the root after the first rotation around it, and never after.

Here is the code:

THE only code I have not included is getMax and getDiff. Get max returns the largest height of the two children and get difference returns the balance of the current node.

Additionally, adjustHeightsH is a helper function that updates the height of every node above the node recently inserted.

```
void AVLTree::adjustHeights(NodeT *n){
    adjustHeightsH(n);
    if(AVLflag){
        if(n->parent == NULL){
            return;
        }
        NodeT *temp = n->parent;
        int balance = getDiff(temp);
        while(temp != NULL){
            balance = getDiff(temp);
            if(balance > 1 && getDiff(temp->left) >= 0){
            rotateRight(temp);
                cout << "rotated right" << endl;
            }
            else if(balance < -1 && getDiff(temp->right) <= 0){
                rotateLeft(temp);
                cout << "rotated left" << endl;
            }
            else if(balance > 1 && getDiff(temp->left) < 0){
                temp->left = rotateLeft(temp->left);
                rotateRight(temp);
                cout << "rotated left right" << endl;
            }
            else if(balance < -1 && getDiff(temp->right) > 0){
                temp->right = rotateRight(temp->right);
                rotateLeft(temp);
                cout << "rotated right left" << endl;
            }
            temp = temp->parent;
        }

    }
}

void AVLTree::adjustHeightsH(NodeT *n){
    NodeT *temp = n;
        while(temp != NULL){
            temp->height = getMax(temp) + 1;
            temp = temp->parent;
        }
}

NodeT *AVLTree::rotateRight(NodeT *n){
    NodeT *temp = n->left;
    NodeT *temp2 = temp->right;

    if(n == root){
        temp->right = n;
        n->left = temp2;
        temp->parent = NULL;
        n->parent = temp;
        root = temp;
        cout << "NEW ROOT" << endl;
    }
    else{
        temp->right = n;
        n->left = temp2;
        temp->parent = n->parent;
        n->parent = temp;
    }


    n->height = getMax(n) + 1;
    temp->height = getMax(temp)+1;
    return temp;
}

NodeT *AVLTree::rotateLeft(NodeT *n){
    NodeT *temp = n->right;
    NodeT *temp2 = temp->left;

    if(n == root){
        temp->left = n;
        n->right = temp2;
        temp->parent = NULL;
        n->parent = temp;
        root = temp;
        cout << "NEW ROOT" << endl;
    }
    else{
        temp->left = n;
        n->right = temp2;
        temp->parent = n->parent;
        n->parent = temp;
    }


    n->height = getMax(n) + 1;
    temp->height = getMax(temp) + 1;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: *but for some reason it only updates the root after the first rotation around it, and never after.* -- Ok, so start to use your debugger to determine where your code diverges from your plan.

Comment: Yeah, what he ^^^ said. Single-step the code in your debugger to find the issue. Although I'm curious why you're using an AVL tree for your dictionary. Seems like a vector or a simple array would be much easier and faster. Load the dictionary into the array (vector), sort it, and then use binary search. Or, if you just want to determine if a string is in the dictionary, use a hash map. An AVL tree is overkill for a static dictionary.